# How to make transparent texture work in .glb/gltf format?

Tags: export, transparency, gltf

I have this transparent model in blender :
[image]

The transparent upper part is a principled BSDF with transmission :
[image]

However when I look at the exported .glb, I get this result using [threejs GLTF viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) :
[image]

I suppose it's because transmission doesn't work for glb/gltf.
How can I make such transparency work as intended ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glTF supports transmission, but it's a very new feature — "alpha blending" transparency is far more widely supported in most 3D engines. Assuming you're using three.js to view the exported model above, you'll need a very recent version, maybe r133+.

Blender does not yet export the volumetric properties (like refraction) associated with transmission, meaning light does not appear to bend passing through the surface. Follow [glTF-Blender-IO#1646](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/1646) for progress on that. In the meantime you can add refraction with tools like [Gestaltor](https://ux3d.io/gestaltor) or a custom script.

Finally, realtime implementations of transmission are often limited to showing only *opaque* materials through the transmissive surface, unlike Blender's Cycles renderer. In Blender that means using *Alpha Mode → Opaque* for objects that should be visible through the transmissive surface.

More details and a demo below:

[image]

https://www.donmccurdy.com/2021/11/11/writing-volumetric-refraction-gltf/

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer, I imported my model in Gestaltor and see the *Transmission* is ticked and working, but I still can't see my bubbles inside the model. I tried finding the *Blend mode* in cycles and went under *Material -> viewport display -> settings* and i've set everything to opaque, but still got the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: Outer material should use Transmission > 0 and *Alpha Mode: Opaque*, inner bubbles should use *Alpha Mode: Opaque* and cannot use transmission. Not sure how your scene is set up but here's an example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NSflhKTfl29r1ec_jzeZCsdJXBtkOOVC/view?usp=sharing ... note that even Blender's own Eevee and Cycles renderers differ on this support.

Comment: Got it! So if I understand correctly it isn't possible to make both the outer material **and** the bubbles transparent ?

Comment: Right — You can set the material up that way, but I don't know of any realtime 3D engine that can render it that way today. Generally need a slower pathtracer like Cycles or [three-gpu-pathtracer](https://github.com/gkjohnson/three-gpu-pathtracer).